# Bundler not installing gems properly during deploy (RVM issue I think)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, vlad-deployer

I've got an app running on a box, and I'm trying to add another to the box.

They both use RVM.

The problem is that my deploy process fails for the new app I've added to the box.

When deploying, I call

```
RVM info
```

to see what ruby I'm using.  Here's the output:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p392:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux li83-41 2.6.39.1-linode34 #1 SMP Tue Jun 21 10:29:24 EDT 2011 i686 GNU/Linux"
    system:      "ubuntu/10.04/i386"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.22.3 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "4 days 21 hours 14 minutes 38 seconds ago"
    path:         "/usr/local/rvm"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "1.9.3p392"
    date:         "2013-02-22"
    platform:     "i686-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2013-02-22 revision 39386"
    full_version: "ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [i686-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392"
    ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
    GEM_HOME:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392"
    GEM_PATH:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392"
    IRBRC:        "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

I'm using bundler, which fails during deploy:

```
cd #{current_path} && bundle install --deployment
```

Throwing this error:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Installing rake (10.1.0)
Installing i18n (0.6.5)
Installing minitest (4.7.5)
Installing multi_json (1.7.9)
Installing atomic (1.1.13)
Installing thread_safe (0.1.2)
Installing tzinfo (0.3.37)
Installing activesupport (4.0.0)
Gem::InstallError: activesupport requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
An error occurred while installing activesupport (4.0.0), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install activesupport -v '4.0.0'` succeeds before bundling.
rake aborted!
```

I'm at wits end here: looks like I'm using ruby1.9.3-p392 but bundler is telling me I need ruby >= 1.9.3.

Here's my .bundle/config:

```
---
BUNDLE_PATH: vendor/bundle
BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: '1'
BUNDLE_FROZEN: '1'
```

Also, if I ssh into the box it looks like I'm using the correct ruby:

```
$ which ruby
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby
```

And Running bundle install works fine.

Any ideas?

**Edit #1**

I'm using Vlad, here's deploy.rb:

```
set :repository,  repo_location
set :revisions,   5
set :revision, "HEAD"
set :domain, domain
set :user,        login_user
set :deploy_to,   deploy_dir
set :deploy_env, "production"

namespace :vlad do

  desc 'Restart Passenger'
  remote_task :restart_app do
    puts "Restarting passenger..."
    run "touch #{current_release}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end

  desc 'Runs our full deployment'
    task :deploy => ['vlad:update', 
                     'vlad:symlink', 
                     'vlad:rvm_info',
                     'vlad:update_bundle',
                     'vlad:migrate_database',
                     'vlad:cleanup', 
                     'vlad:restart_app']

  desc 'Symlinks your custom directories'
  remote_task :symlink do
    run "ln -s #{shared_path}/environments #{latest_release}/config/environments"
    run "ln -s #{shared_path}/database.yml #{current_path}/config/database.yml"
    run "ln -s #{shared_path}/config.yml #{current_path}/config/config.yml"
  end

  desc 'Show RVM Info for debug purposes'
  remote_task :rvm_info do
    run "cd #{current_path} && rvm info" 
  end

  desc 'Update the Bundler bundle we use to include any new gems in the Gemfile'
  remote_task :update_bundle do
    run "cd #{current_path} && bundle install --deployment" 
  end

  # copied from the vlad source, integrate migrate does not work as it's missing
  # the && between the cd and the db migrate task itself. bug is already tracked
  # at http://rubyforge.org/tracker/?group_id=4213&atid=16258&func=detail&aid=28445, 
  # but currently does not do anything.
  remote_task :migrate, :roles => :app do
    break unless target_host == Rake::RemoteTask.hosts_for(:app).first

    directory = case migrate_target.to_sym
                when :current then current_path
                when :latest  then latest_release
                else raise(ArgumentError, "unknown migration target #{migrate_target.inspect}")
                end

    run(["cd #{directory}", 
         "bundle exec #{rake_cmd} db:migrate #{migrate_args} RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}"].join(" && "))
  end

end
```

Comment: Are you using capistrano? If yes, show the capfile

Comment: I'm using Vlad - updated the question with deploy.rb.

Answer (score 0):

It is not rvm fault ... this is issue with how you are running your commands, `vlad` does not use login session like it is done with `ssh` so you need to load rvm manually:

```
set :command_prefix, [". `/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm . do rvm env --path`"]
```

I have no way of testing it - based it on vlad code - but this should be a good start.